# Fields of java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D?

Tags: java, processing

Not a Java person here, I'm just trying this code in [Processing.org](http://processing.org/):

```
//import java.awt.Rectangle; // int only
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D; 

Rectangle2D testr;

void setup() {
  testr = new Rectangle2D.Float(1.0, 1.0, 30.0, 30.0);
  println(testr);
  //println(testr.x);
}
```

It prints out:

```
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float[x=1.0,y=1.0,w=30.0,h=30.0]
```

... which sort of implies where are `x` and `y` fields accessible? Even [Rectangle2D.Float (Java Platform SE 7 )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Float.html) says:

> Field Summary
>   ...
>   float     x
>   The X coordinate of this Rectangle2D.

And yet, if I uncomment `println(testr.x);`, compilation fails with:

```
testr.x cannot be resolved or not a field.
```

Where am I going wrong - and why cannot I access a field, which the documentation clearly says exists?

Btw, this is what I find in `/tmp` as the full `.java` source when the processing `.pde` manages to compile:

```
import processing.core.*; 
import processing.data.*; 
import processing.event.*; 
import processing.opengl.*; 

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D; 

import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.PrintWriter; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 

public class sketch_140204c extends PApplet {


//import java.awt.Rectangle; // int only


Rectangle2D testr;

public void setup() {
  testr = new Rectangle2D.Float(1.0f, 1.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
  println(testr);
}

  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "sketch_140204c" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
      PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
      PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to directly access those properties, but instead call the public getter methods.

Comment: Thanks for that, @HovercraftFullOfEels - can you please explain how to infer that from the docs? To me, [java.awt.Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) describes its fields similarly, and yet there I _can_ read `rect.x` without a problem?

Comment: That's the Rectangle API. The one you're interested in is the [Rectangle2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html). Check out the methods of its supper class for getX(), getY(), etc.

Comment: OFC that these fields are accesible, but to the class itself and classes from the same package. Not to the outside classes (non related). That what lack of public/protected/private keyword do.

Comment: Thanks, @HovercraftFullOfEels - I guess my problem is, why doesn't the documentation clearly state that for `java.awt.Rectangle`, fields `.x` are accessible; while for `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D`, those fields are not accessible?

Comment: Thanks, @Antoniossss - that would explain it; still, I wonder why the documentations doesn't state clearly when the fields are private (I tried ctrl-F private on both Rectangle and Rectangle2D doc pages) ...

Comment: What documentation? according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html those fields has no modificators so they are package protected.

Comment: @Antoniossss - [java.awt.Rectangle (Java Platform SE 7 )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) and [java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float (Java Platform SE 7 )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Float.html)... btw, turns out private fields are not the problem - see accepted answer below.

Comment: @Antoniossss - aha, thanks: so the way to read that documentation is: if there are no modificators to the fields, then they are package protected, correct? How come then, the accepted answer works for me?

Comment: I don't know what is working for you as I don't see your code. I can just assume that you start using public fields of `Rectangle2D` insteed of package protected from `Rectangle2D.Float` And as about modifiers, take look at this website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Thanks, @Antoniossss - I didn't get that `Rectangle2D` has public fields, and `Rectangle2D.Float` has package protected fields; your last comment clarified that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These fields are declared on [`Rectangle2D.Float`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Float.html) but `testr` is just a `Rectangle2D`. Changing its declaration will let you access them since they are public:

```
Rectangle2D.Float testr;
```

It's a good suggestion to use getters and setters but there aren't individual setters for these classes. Only setters to set the entire rectangle (namely [setRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html#setRect%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29)).

Comment: Many, many thanks, @Radiodef - just tried it, it works! So the problem was not private/public setting of fields.. Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: this is not a good solution in my view as you're coding away from the abstract towards the concrete, and you're breaking encapsulation. Why not simply use the public getter methods?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - basically, I'm working on a simple example for students in Processing for students, where proper Java syntax/best practices is not of primary concern. So first, I tried `awt.Rectangle` - but as I need floats for my example, and `awt.Rectangle` is int-only, I thought - why not try `awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Float`, it seems to be made for that. And I made the mistake to declare my variable as `Rectangle2D` (instead of `Rectangle2D.Float`), so I got the error-either way, I would have still been at loss in explaining why I can use `Rectangle.x` but not `Rectangle2D.Float.x`...

Comment: ... @HovercraftFullOfEels (cont.) - and this solution allows me to use the `.x` syntax both places. And also, I'd rather write in Processing, `rect( myrect.x+5.0, myrect.y, myrect.width, myrect.height );` as a single drawing command, than `rect( myrect.getX()+5.0, myrect.getY(), myrect.getWidth(), myrect.getHeight() );`... Hope this explains - cheers!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels These objects do not really have any encapsulation to speak of and, as I said, there are not setters except to set the entire rectangle at once (which is more like a convenience). They just get channeled to draw/fill and I would be more willing to agree that they should only be created temporarily (not a field).

Answer (score 0):

These fields are declared on Rectangle2D.Float you can print to control.

```
Ellipse2D.Float test= new Ellipse2D.Float(getPosX()-40,getPosY()-40,30.0f, 30.0f);
        System.out.println(test.getCenterX());
        System.out.println(test.getCenterY());
        System.out.println(test.getMinX());
        System.out.println(test.getMinY());
        System.out.println(test.getMaxX());
        System.out.println(test.getMaxY());
```